# Deploying CodeStar application to Spot Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codestar

Is there an easy way to automatically deploy a CodeStar application to a persistent spot instance every time the request is fulfilled? The pipeline only runs when the code is changed and requires that the codedeploy agent already be installed. I've searched online and can't seem to find anything regarding using CodeStar with spot instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems totally possible, please read [Deploying AWS CodeDeploy Applications to Auto Scaling Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html#integrations-aws-auto-scaling-deploy)

> AWS CodeDeploy supports Auto Scaling, an AWS service that can launch Amazon EC2 instances automatically according to conditions you define. These conditions can include limits exceeded in a specified time interval for CPU utilization, disk reads or writes, or inbound or outbound network traffic. Auto Scaling terminates the instances when they are no longer needed. For more information, see What Is Auto Scaling?.
>
> When new Amazon EC2 instances are launched as part of an Auto Scaling
>   group, AWS CodeDeploy can deploy your revisions to the new instances
>   automatically. You can also coordinate deployments in AWS CodeDeploy
>   with Amazon EC2 instances registered with Elastic Load Balancing load
>   balancers. For more information, see Integrating AWS CodeDeploy with
>   Elastic Load Balancing and Set Up a Classic Load Balancer in Elastic
>   Load Balancing for AWS CodeDeploy Deployments.

Good luck